# HTML: How to force IE11 to emulate IE9 in HTML?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

How to force IE11 in html to use IE9 css styles.

I used this code

```
<script runat="server">
        private void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var meta = new HtmlMeta();
            meta.Content = "IE=EmulateIE9";
            meta.HttpEquiv = "X-UA-Compatible";
            this.Page.Header.Controls.AddAt(0, meta);
        }
</script>
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
```

To get the same stylres when is internet explorer for all versions, taking ie9 as standard.

I am doing this code:

```
<!--[if IE]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/App_Themes/CocktailSite/master-interno-ie.css" media="screen" />
   <!--[else]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/App_Themes/CocktailSite/master-interno.css" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->
```

it is working when is IE9 and take master-interno-ie.css but in IE11 takes master-interno.

I was wahching all answer here and not worked in my case.

Comment: The if else is irrelevant since you're including the same file.

Comment: i have X-UA-Compatible metatag over the <title>

Comment: doodlebunch how do i do it then? in two if?

Comment: I saw i had the same but bellow else is without -ie in the name of the file, error to type

Answer (score 0):

[IE no longer evaluates conditional HTML comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> **As of Internet Explorer 10**, conditional comments are no longer
>   supported by standards mode. Use feature detection to provide
>   effective fallback strategies for website features that aren't
>   supported by the browser.

Comment: I was looking the link you added here and that link dont recognize ie11

Answer (score 0):

I got it using jQuery.

between scripts and link i coded this:

```
function isIE() {
    var sAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var Idx = sAgent.indexOf("MSIE");

    // If IE, return version number.
    if (Idx > 0) return true;    
    // If IE 11 then look for Updated user agent string.
    else if (!!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./)) return true;
    else return false; //It is not IE
}
```

After it I aded:

```
if (isIE()) {
    jQuery('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"     href="~/App_Themes/CocktailSite/master-interno-ie.css" media="screen" />');
}
```

it is working for my neededs.

TESTED FOR ALL IE versions, CHROME AND FIREFOX