# ie11 to ie9 compatibility mode by javascript

Tags: compatibility

I'm working with SP2010 environment
By default the master page come with a meta tag:

> meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"

Which presents my forms (InfoPath) in a good view in all browsers except IE11

If I try to add to the meta tags IE=9 or edge, it'll fix the problem in IE11, but all the other explorers go blank.

Is there a way to stay with the 1st  meta tags (IE=8), & to add a javascript that's tell the **IE11 only** to compatible to IE9?

I try a lot of option I found here & the web, like this:
[HTML: How to force IE11 to emulate IE9 in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156995/html-how-to-force-ie11-to-emulate-ie9-in-html)

But nothing works…

Answer (score 0):

For IE11, you can try using [Enterprise mode](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn640687).

Hope this helps...

-- Lance